# How to fix 401 (Unauthorized) error for GET request in Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I log in to an app then make an axios GET request to the database. However, a 401 (Unauthorized) error is returned. How can I fix this?

[image: screenshot of error]

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Without more information on how the server handles the request, it is impossible to answer this question. Sorry.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8289918) It makes it harder for others to read your code, reproduce the scenario, and answer your question. Also, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.

Answer (score 0):

401 means the request didn't take the token in request headers.
I think you need to check if the token exists

```
  let token = localStorage.getItem('user')
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
  } else {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
  }
```

or if you want to make all requests bring token, you can user axios interceptors to intercept all requests to add authorization headers and handle the response.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (store.getters.token) {
        config.headers['x-token'] = getToken();
    }
    return config;
});
axios.interceptors.response.use( response=>{
    const res = response.data
    if (res.code != 200) {
        Message({
            message: res.data || "Error",
            type: 'error'
        })
        if(res.code == 401) {
            MessageBox.confirm(res.data, '重新登录', {
                confirmButtonText: '确定',
                type: 'warning'
            }).then(() => {
                store.dispatch('user/logout')
                window.location.replace('/login')
            })
        }
        return res
    } else {
        return res
    }
})
```